# File created on desktop through shell doesn't show on desktop in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, desktop

When I am creating a folder on Debian in console by `mkdir` in desktop, I see this folder in console, but I can't see it on the desktop.

How can I enable the desktop in Debian?

Comment: Heavily depends on the desktop environment / window manager. Which one are you using?

Comment: which directory are you in, give the pwd command, mostly if you are in root and you want to create a folder in Desktop the directory would be /root/Desktop similarly for any user it would be /home/user/Desktop.

Comment: Some distros, even big distros dont show desktop contents except for mounted drives and `.desktop` files. usually there is an option somewhere to "let the window manager handle the desktop"

Answer (score 2):

You must enable the option to have the file manager handle the desktop. 
If you are using the gnome desktop environment this is very easy. 
Just install the gnome-tweak-tool, open it, go to the option 'desktop' and then enable the option 'Have file manager handle the dektop'.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you are working on the desktop directory: `cd Desktop`

It will be useful to know which desktop environment are you using.